LG 49WL95C flickering white lines
I was connecting my MacBook Pro via the USB-C cable directly from the monitor port to my laptop. I unplugged the cable from my laptop then plugged it back in (probably within 2 mins), these horizontal white lines started to display.
It was literally working a few minutes before this.
I’ve tried everything from unplugging all cables and checking it’s properly plugged in and all.
I purchased this monitor during the pandemic so it’s definitely out of warranty. To top it off, LG also has discontinued this product line.
LG quoted me $800 to repair which is almost the price of the monitor itself.
What I’d want to know is:
Is it best practice to not unplug and plug frequently if connecting source to monitor directly instead of through a hub? Or did I just get unlucky that the last connection broke something.
This seems like a hardware issue. Are there any signs to what exactly?
Any recommendations to fix?
Forgot to mention - even when powering on the monitor these lines display with nothing connected such as my laptop.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uYadSQvnsQ9c0UqjuPt826W2uw7SiebF/view?usp=drivesdk
Example photo of white lines:


Welcome to Superuser!  Please upload pictures directly to the question instead of posting links to Google Drive.  It is 1) more trusted by the community, and 2) less likely to suffer link rot over time.

I didn't click on your Google Drive link (sorry, nothing personal), but it very much sounds like a hardware issue with the monitor.  Unlikely this is going to help but something you could try is plugging the power directly into the wall if it's plugged into a strip/surge protector, or switching outlets.  Most likely, though, is that the panel is starting to go.

Thanks for the tips - first time poster! I will update post with a photo to hopefully gain some others that are weary of clicking on a link.

After a quick Google search, I found [this][https://www.lg.com/us/support/help-library/lg-monitor-troubleshooting-lines-on-the-screen--20153186572241] article from LG themselves, and it seems like it may be more likley a hardware issue. Have you tried these steps, LeD37?

Update: I was able to fix the lines with scotch tape as instructed in this video. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SbGAkRgaZhs
Hopefully, this gives me a few more years with my monitor without having to drop $$ to fix it.
